# Convert bashrc function into a script/command?

Tags: bash, function, scripting

I created the following function in a bash terminal as a way to move and immediately see the files in a directory.

```
function cnl { (cd $* ; pwd ; ls --color) }
```

It works fine as an addition to `.bashrc`, but I would like to turn it into a command that can be called from a script in my `~/bin` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file in `~/bin` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $*
pwd
ls --color
```

and make it executable:

```
chmod u+x ~/bin/your_script
```

Comment: thank you. I had figured out a bit more complex method, but yours is much cleaner.

Comment: Use of `$*` in this context is odd and unlikely be actually be desirable. There are very few cases where `cd` takes more than one argument and even in those the behaviour of unquoted `$*` is unlikely to be necessary. That should almost certainly either be `$1` or `"$@"`. And yes, I realize that is direct from the OP but this comment makes more sense on the answer than on the question.

Comment: I understand that $1 takes the first argument, but can you tell me what $@ does?

Comment: `"$@"` is the entire list of arguments, with embedded quoting etc preserved.  So if you run `script "foo bar" 'ick "oh" poo'` the only way to correctly refer to this command line where `$1` is `foo bar` and `$2` is `ick "oh" poo` is by using `"$@"`.  I believe that historically, the original shell did not handle this situation correctly at all; at the time, only `$*` was available.

Comment: If you actually want to run this with multiple arguments, I suppose it ought to be `local f; for f; do cd "$f"; pwd; ls --color; done` where a bare `for f` is shorthand for `for f in "$@"`.

Comment: +1 for the implicit observation that the parentheses become superfluous when you migrate from a function to a script!